# WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID cannot be disabled for ZonedDateTime

Tags: jackson

I'm using Jackson 2.8.1 for serialization of java object. However, I just can't git rid of zone id when converting a ZonedDateTime object to a string with "WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID" set to false

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .findAndRegisterModules()
            .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY)
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID, false);

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(zdt)); // "2016-08-23T13:35:38.127+08:00[Asia/Shanghai]"
```

Can any one help?

Comment: something  is missing in your example while it prints all field of `ZonedDateTime` objects `{"dayOfMonth":23,"dayOfWeek":"TUESDAY","dayOfYear":236,"month":"AUGUST","monthValue":8,"year":2016,"hour":14,"minute":40,"nano":745000000,"second":3,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"}}`.

Comment: @MichalFoksa you may need to have jackson-datatype-jsr310 in your class path

Comment: What is your expected value? `2016-08-23T13:35:38.127` or `2016-08-23T13:35:38.127+08:00`?

Comment: @MichalFoksa I was expecting the latter one, which is without zone id string

Answer (score 3):

I would say the issue is because you call "findAndRegisterModules".

You probably added the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Doing so, you introduced two new modules: "JSR310Module" (deprecated) and "JavaTimeModule".

"findAndRegisterModules" can register the "JSR310Module" that is not supporting properly the WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID feature.

You can register the right module by removing "findAndRegisterModules" and adding:

```
JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
registerModule(module);
```

Then, don't forget to disable WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID in your mapper:

```
disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_WITH_ZONE_ID);
```

Comment: You just saved me a lot of time :-)